# What is the meaning of quaternion interpolation?

Tags: complex-analysis, geometry, quaternions

Suppose I take the average between two quaternions, how does one see the meaning of the resulting rotation to make sure it is sensible, unlike interpolating Euler angles?

I'm looking for an argument that would show that rotating a point by the new quaternion is equivalent to rotating it by the original two and then going half way on the great circle arc in between.

Comment: related question: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/686901/115115

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to assume that both are unit quaternions. Rotate everything so that the first quaternion is 1. Then the second is $\cos α+n\sin α$ with $n$ being a purely imaginary unit quaternion. The midpoint is now at
$$
\frac12 [ (1+\cosα)+n\sin α]=\cos \tfracα2[\cos \tfracα2+n\sin\tfracα2]
$$
so that indeed if $\cos \tfracα2\ne 0$ the midpoint after normalization gives the rotation with same rotation axis and half the angle.

---

For general interpolation between two quaternions with constant rotation velocity, see my [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/687459/115115) to a similar question, or any other source on quaternions and rotation. In short,

- compute the decomposition $q_1^{-1}q_2=\cosα+\vec n\sinα$, or more specifically, the angle $α$ between the two quaternions, as before,
- then the interpolation is given as $$q(t)=\frac{\sin((1-t)α)}{\sinα}q_1+\frac{\sin(tα)}{\sinα}q_2$$

Comment: I wonder, is there a way to foresee this property without going through trigonometric formulas?

Comment: It is the classical angle bisector construction, for any vectors $a$ and $b$, the vector $\|b\|\,a+\|a\|\,b$ and any multiple of it bisects the angle between $a$ and $b$.

Comment: Can we apply the same "rotate everything so that the first quaternion is 1" proof technique to interpolating between axis-angle representations and conclude the same? If not, where is the failing point?

Comment: This is a bit more difficult, but not much. You want to go at the same speed along, you have to use the trigonometric function in the interpolation. I'll add a link to the answer.

Comment: Thanks but I think my remark was misunderstood. I'd like to compare quaternions to another representation in terms of interpolation. the angle and axis representation is a 4D vector similar to the quaternion. My question is: what is the result of taking the average between two such representations? Is it the same rotation we'd get had we averaged quaternions?

Comment: No, in all probability you will get an unrelated result, especially if the angle between the axes is rather large. If both angles and axes do not differ much, then it should make no large difference which midpoint you take.

Comment: Can't we apply the same proof as above?
Let us rotate everything so that the first angle-axis pair means no rotation at all, $(0,n)$, the second pair is then $(\alpha,n)$. The average is very sensible: $(\alpha/2, n)$.